# Verifying WordPress accounts by a unique composite Id

Tags: php, hash

**Update of problem**

**Use Case**

The Software System makes use of data provided by a WordPress accounts e.g. user id. There is a change that two WordPress account don't have the same unique user id or username because they run in there own environment. But because they all make use of the environment provided by my software system, an unique id is a requirement.

So, for the system to verify the authenticity of every WordPress account (that makes use of it), it must have some reference to the particular WordPress account. I thought of creating a combination of user id and username to make it unique.

**Example**

```
<?php

global 
$current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

$hash =  crc32($current_user->user_login);
```

> Output: 385153371 === root

```
$unique_id = $hash . $current_user->ID;
```

> Output: 385153371{2} === root{2}

**Records example**

[image]
[image]

Comment: why not just get your database to generate a unique ID as a primary key? You can set a uniqueness constraint on the username field as well to make sure they aren't duplicated. Or use username as the primary key and have some validation in the UI/API layer (depending on your program's structure) to check for duplicates before inserting. It's unclear why you'd need to do your suggested process.

Comment: Even if you did, it's unclear why the number of digits in the returned number would be of significance in that. Just adding an arbitrary 10th digit to it wouldn't guarantee uniqueness either, I don't think, since you could easily add the same digit again to the same hash output. You say the 10th digit is the primary key, but then if your primary key is only 1 digit, you must be limited to 10 users (0 - 9) before you have a key violation.

Comment: It's a 32-bit integer (hence crc32), with an unsigned range of 0 to 4,294,967,295; but can return a negative number on 32-bit PHP systems (giving a range of −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647); so potentially 10 digits, and a sign

Comment: @ADyson: I suspect that it may be used in e.g. part of a URL. You can't use only the PK in that case since the pattern would be far too regular and could be a security liability.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Which is why we have unique id algorithms such as UUIDv4.

Comment: "two users can have the same username"  wtf? What kind of system allows multiple users with the same username?

Comment: @ADyson, I updated my problem with an explanation of a higher view of the problem. I hope this explains it more clearly.

Comment: hm. in that case it would make more sense to use a compound key which is made up of the Wordpress ID, and and ID representing the environment it belongs to. Usefully that also gives you a record of where the data relates back to, and you don't have to generate the IDs yourself.

Answer (score 2):

A CRC32 hash is 8 hexadecimal digits in length. This means that it may be as many as 10 decimal digits in length with an optional sign character. If you want to use it as part of a larger scheme then you should make certain that it is 0-padded to full length.